# Equivalent %username% for VB script

Tags: vbscript

I am looking to delete OfficeFileCache folder from the current user's computer. Currently I have..

```
Option Explicit
Dim obj : Set obj =CreateObject ("wscript.shell")
Dim fso : Set fso =CreateObject ("scripting.FileSystemObject")

obj.Run "taskkill /f /im msouc.exe.exe",0
obj.Run "taskkill /f /im msosync.exe.exe",0

fso.DeleteFolder "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache"
```

The last part is what I am having trouble with. Just looking for an equivalent to usernames within a VB script.

Comment: simply: `fso.DeleteFolder obj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache")`

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/dy8116cf%28v%3dvs.84%29):

> ### ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method
>
> Returns an environment variable's expanded value.

In your case:

```
fso.DeleteFolder obj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some path like

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\...
```

This is better:

```
%LocalAppData%\...
```

So

```
Fso.DeleteFolder Obj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache")
```

does it better, in case the user set their `%UserProfile%` to another directory.